# Exclude chapter from TOC, without removing numbering

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I am trying to exclude an entry from my table of contents, but I want to keep the numbering, so e.g. `\chapter*{}` won't work for me.

I googled around a bit, but all solutions seem to be equivalent to `\chapter*{}`.

The reason for my problem is that I'm adding a "list of appendices" below the TOC, so I need numbering for referencing, but it looks kind of dumb to have the list in the TOC as well.

Comment: just do `{\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}
\chapter{Bla bla}}`

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Here's another proposition with `tocdepth` counter manipulation, however, this won't prevent the addition of the relevant chapter in the bookmarks.

```
\documentclass{book}


\newcounter{oldtocdepth}

\newcommand{\hidefromtoc}{%
  \setcounter{oldtocdepth}{\value{tocdepth}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{-10}}%
}

\newcommand{\unhidefromtoc}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{oldtocdepth}}}%
}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo chapter}


\hidefromtoc
\chapter{List of Appendices}
\unhidefromtoc
\chapter{Other foo chapter}

\end{document}
```

The screen shot shows the unpleasant feature of the request: If there's another chapter afterwards, there's a gap in counting in the ToC, however, since it is the appendix, there are no further chapters after the appendix, most likely.

[image]

Comment: The unpleasant feature doesn't matter, the appendix is the last part of my document.

Comment: Your solution works, but in order to make it work as intended, I have to throw in the \hidefromtoc before the chapter previous from the one I want to hide, like this:

\chapter{unhidden chapter}
\hidefromtoc
\chapter{last unhidden chapter}
\appendix
\chapter{first hidden chapter}
..
\chapter{last hidden chapter}
\unhidefromtoc
\end{document}

Maybe this is because of the appendix environment, I don't know.
Either way, your solution works when I do that, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @AndersOlsen: Please consider to accept the solution then.